# Ruby on Rails request to not returning & no info in log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, loading

When you execute an action on my application (only one action) the browser will just sit there not doing anything, when i check my **production.log** i see the request (about 2 minutes after i go to the address) but i see no errors or problems, while the browser never stops "**Loading**". I checked my NGINX server logs, and didn't find anything, and this problem doesn't happen in my development environment. My log level is set to debug.

I've had the issue reported by two other people, so it isn't just my machine. Any clue what could be causing this or what i could do to debug it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try taking NGINX out of the loop. Try running your app from the console with `script/server -e production` and then see if you can access the server on localhost:3000, i.e. `curl http://localhost:3000`

Comment: This was a good step, after examining the log a little more in detail, i realized i was performing a select statement on a table with 275k entries, and no index. The database was just taking forever, and rather than timing out on the browser refresh, or giving me a loaded page, for some reason it just hung there. Thanks for the help.